# Behat: How to clean up database records created in the scenario

Tags: php, symfony, behat

I have the following scenario:

```
    @mink:selenium2
  Scenario: Login
    Given there are the following users:
      | username | password | email               |
      | admin    | 1234     | admin@socialcar.com |
    When I am on "/login"
    And I fill in "username" with "admin"
    And I fill in "password" with "1234"
    And I press "Login"
    Then I should be on "/admin"
```

So I'd like to have a cleanupUsers as a @AfterScenario where I can clean whatever was inserted in the scenario. So how can I access the TableNode of users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save your users in a private property so that you could access them later in [a hook](http://docs.behat.org/en/latest/guides/3.hooks.html#scenario-hooks):

```
private $users;

/**
 * @Given there are the following users:
 */
public function thereAreFollowingUsers(TableNode $table)
{
    $this->users = $table;

    // ...
}

/**
 * @AfterScenario
 */
public function cleanupUsers(AfterScenarioScope $scope)
{
    if (null !== $this->users) {
        // do the cleanups
        // ...

        // reset the property
        $this->users = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According [the doc](http://docs.behat.org/en/v3.0/guides/3.hooks.html#scenario-hooks): hooks "will also have access to any object properties you set during your scenario".

So I think you just need to save the `TableNode` (or better, just the created user ids) in a property of your context class in the code of the `Given there are the following users` step, and then use it in `cleanupUsers`.